# Fix Error writing to store for query QUERYNAME

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I have a page with infinite loading enabled. I pull and skip thru a list of notices. Trouble Im facing is, I get a console error.

I've tried providing the skip number and no luck. It doesn't break anything but it's an annoying error.

What could be causing this?

Error: Error writing result to  store for query:

```
 query ($limit: Int, $skip: Int) {
  getNotifications(limit: $limit, skip: $skip) {
    notifications {
      id
      seen
      read
      type
      text
      topicID
      date
      fromProfile {
        profilePic
        profileName
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    total
    unseen
    __typename
  }
}
```

Store error: the application attempted to write an object with no provided typename but the store already contains an object with typename of NotficationListType for the object of id $ROOT_QUERY.getNotifications({"limit":5}). The selectionSet that was trying to be written is:

```
getNotifications(limit: $limit, skip: $skip) {
  notifications {
    id
    seen
    read
    type
    text
    topicID
    date
    fromProfile {
      profilePic
      profileName
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
  total
  unseen
  __typename
}
```

Comment: Are you writing anything explicitly to the cache (i.e.: using `cache.writeQuery`)?

Comment: Yes I was. And the structure was wrong. Doh.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you were doing wrong and how did you fix it?

Comment: Basically edited the query data directly and used that to write to the query. I was trying to rewrite it and push that instead before.